# How to remove objects from a list bound to an ObservableCollection in C# MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to use the MVVM pattern in C#. Therefore I have a customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustumerNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

I fill a list with Customers from a database:

```
public class CustomerList
{
    public static List<Customer> customerlist = new List<Customer>();

    public static List<Customer> GetCustomer()
    {
    // Get data from database
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public string CustomerSearch { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
         Customers = new ObservableColletion<Customers>(CustomerList.GetCustomer());
    }
}
```

I bound Customers in an WPF-ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
DisplayMemberPath="CustomerName"/>
```

Let's say I have 10 objects of CustomerName in the ListBox. There is a TextBox that contains a string. Now I want to remove all objects in the ListBox that don't contain the string. I solved the problem in the ViewModel as follows:

```
public void SearchCustomer()
{
    foreach (Customer item in Customers)
    {
        if (item.Customers.ToUpper().Contains(CustomerSearch.ToUpper()) == false)
        {
            this.Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(CustomerList.RemoveItemsFromView(item));
        }
    }
}
```

Is this right? It feels wrong to me, because every time the loop removes an item I create a new `ObservableCollection` instead of manipulating the existing one. Is there a more professional way to solve this task?

For the `PropertyChangeEvent` I use FodyWeaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create a new source collection, you could remove items from the existing one. Just make sure that you don't call the `Remove` method in a `foreach` loop.

This should work:

```
for (int i = Customers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Customer item = Customers[i];
    if (item.Customers.ToUpper().Contains(CustomerSearch.ToUpper()) == false)
    {
        Customers.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

If you do reset the collection property each time you want to add or remove an item, you might as well use a `List<T>`. Just make sure that you raise a property notification when the property is set.

Comment: Works fine for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the Customer item you can just do this inside your if:

```
this.Customers.Remove(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method `Remove` from `Customers` like you are doing with `CustomerList`. Or update `Customers` after the loop:

**First Option**

```
foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
{
    if (!customer.Customers.ToUpper().Contains(CustomerSearch.ToUpper()))
    {
        CustomerList.RemoveItemsFromView(customer);
        Customers.Remove(customer);
    }
}
```

**Second Option**

```
foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
{
    if (!customer.Customers.ToUpper().Contains(CustomerSearch.ToUpper()))
    {
        CustomerList.RemoveItemsFromView(customer);
    }
}

this.Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(CustomerList);
```

I can't suggest you more options without havig `CustomerList` and `RemoveItemsFromView` source code.

Also, I refactored a bit the code. Having a good name for variables is important. And if looks a bit wrong, but I don't have your model.

Comment: Your first option was the first that I tried by myself, but it creates an exception. I thank you anyway, mm8's answer worked fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, because the use of the foreach, sorry for that. The second option didn't work? If you use it the View will only get refreshed once. Instead of everytime you use RemoveAt.